# SQL Serverでのダミーデータ作成

Tags: sql, sql-server

以下の様なテーブルがあるとします。

table:m_tbl

```
ID  AreaCode
--- ---
1   0000000001
2   0000000002
3   0000000003
4   0000000021
5   0000000044
.   .
.   .
.   .
```

- IDが主キー
- AreaCodeの重複は可
- データは50万件

これらのデータを利用してIDを振り直しながら500億件(50,000,000,000)のデータを登録したいと考えています。

こういった場合、どのようなSQL文になるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT ～ SELECT ～`を10回実行すればよいのではないでしょうか。

```
INSERT INTO other (AreaCode)
SELECT AreaCode FROM m_tbl
```

上記は`ID`が`IDENTITY`列という想定で省略していますが、必要であれば適当に追加してください。

繰り返し部分もTransact-SQLで記述するのであれば`WHILE`ステートメントを使用して以下のようになります。

```
DECLARE
    @i int = 1;
BEGIN
    WHILE @i <= 10
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO other (AreaCode)
            SELECT AreaCode FROM m_tbl;

            SET @i = @i + 1;

        END
END
```